How to include multiple observations in timeseries multiple linear regression?
I want to know how much variance in signal y can be explained by signals of class x. I have multiple observations of signals of class x. Take the simple multiple linear regression model:
$y = B_0 + B_1X$
It seems to me there are several ways to do this:

Use all signals of class x as columns in the design matrix X and take the mean of all the betas to represent the average effect of signals of class x on y. I assume this is a poor choice because of high multicolinearity between signals of class x?
Average all signals of class x and this reduces to a simple linear regression.
Concatenate all signals of class x into one long time-series. Concatenate signal y onto itself until it matches the length of x. Proceed with simple linear regression.

Which one of these approaches is preferred? Or is there a better alternative that I have not thought of?
Edit: For additional context -
These are neural signals (fMRI BOLD) and I am trying to assess the connectivity between brain regions by looking at how much variance in region y is explained by multiple regions (xs) that share similar properties (ex. they are all responsive to visual stimuli).

Welcome to CV.  This question has multiple good answers depending on what these signals mean and how you model their relationship.  Please, then, elaborate on those.

Thank you. Yes, these are neural signals (fMRI BOLD) and I am trying to assess the connectivity between brain regions by looking at how much variance in region y is explained by multiple regions (xs) that share similar properties. I will edit the question with this extra information

whuber raises a good point in his comment as the answer to your question depends on what the signals mean and how you model their relationship. I will try expanding on these and include possible reasons one may follow each method:

This approach is generally not preferred due to the high multicollinearity between signals of class x, as you correctly pointed out. It can lead to unstable estimates and difficult interpretation. I would only use this method if you have a small number of relatively independent x signals OR, you're specifically interested in the individual effects of each x signal on y OR the sample size is much larger than the number of predictors.

This method is simple and reduces multicollinearity issues, but it may lose important information about individual signal contributions. It's a viable option if you're primarily interested in the overall effect and believe the average adequately represents the class x signals.

While this preserves more information than averaging, it can introduce artificial patterns and inflate the sample size, potentially leading to overconfident estimates. It's generally not recommended unless you have strong reasons to believe the relationship is consistent across all concatenated segments.


An alternative to also consider is Principal Component Regression (PCR) which allows you to capture the majority of variance in the x signals while addressing multicollinearity. Essentially, in PCR you:

Perform Principal Component Analysis (PCA) on the x signals.
Select a subset of principal components that explain a sufficient amount of variance in x (e.g., 95%).
Use these principal components as predictors in a multiple linear regression model with y as the response variable.

The R-squared of this model will give you the proportion of variance in y explained by the selected principal components of x.
Please feel free to ask any questions or elaborate further.

Thank you, this makes sense. I will look into PCR. I also added additional context to the post about what the signals are. An additional question about PCR - if I had multiple brain regions for my Ys that all shared a similar property (ex. visual responsive regions) as well as multiple brain regions for my Xs (ex. auditory responsive regions), could I use PCA on the Y signals as well? Then do PCR with n components for predictors and i components for dependent variables? I assume then it would turn into a multivariate multiple regression?

Yes, you can and this is called Canonical Correlation Analysis.
Here's how it would work:


Perform PCA on the X signals (auditory-responsive regions), retaining n components.


Perform PCA on the Y signals (visual-responsive regions), retaining i components.


Perform a multivariate multiple regression using the n components from X to predict the i components from Y.


